# Can't pass multiple variables via metamask - async error

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am getting an error in metamask "the MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter".
I am trying to pass three parameters to a solidity function, but the callbacks I've tried to insert don't seem to work?

Below is the js code, just a button and 3 labels for the variables in the HTML

```
$('#proposalbutton').click(function() {
    log("Calling add proposals...");
    community.newProposal($("#address").text(), $("#coinAmount").val(), 
                          $("#jobDescription").text()), (err, res) =>{
        if (!err) {
            log("Proposals call executed successfully.");;
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure out the callbacks.
Below is the solidity function header

```
function newProposal(
    address beneficiary,
    uint coinAmount,
    string jobDescription
)
onlyMembers public
returns (uint proposalID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are the last parameter sent after your Solidity contract parameters. It looks like you're closing `newProposal` after just the function parameter list.

```
community.newProposal($("#address").text(), $("#coinAmount").val(), 
                      $("#jobDescription").text(), (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
        log("Proposals call executed successfully.");;
    }
});
```

Additional note: Transaction methods won't return a value. You won't get `proposalID` in your response. Use either an event or store the result in your contract state and then use a `view` function to return it.

Comment: Thanks, is the event in the function?